# Accessing dynamically created variable in onclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a foreach loop, enumerating my models to create a table. In this table, i need to have an edit button for each model where i call a javascript function to show a modal.

I need to pass the model into the javascript function, but i can't get this to work. I've worked out how to dynamically create the variables, but not how to use it as input.

Right now, it's just hardcoded to use 'department1', which is just the first created. I need toggleManageDepartmentModal to be called with (department + @department.Id)

**Creating the table**

```
@foreach (var department in Model.PaginatedDepartments())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@department.Name</td>
                    <td>@department.Description</td>
                    <td class="min">@department.Created.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td>
                    <td class="min">
                        <div class="text-nowrap">
                            <script>
                                //Dynamically create variables for each department
                                eval('var department' + @department.Id + '= @Json.Serialize(department);');
                            </script>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="toggleManageDepartmentModal(department1)">
                                <span class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                Rediger
                            </button>
                        </div>   
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

**Javascript function to show modal**

```
function toggleManageDepartmentModal(department) {
        var model = {
            department : department,
            controller : 'Admin',
            action : 'ManageDepartment'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Modals/ShowManageDepartmentModal",
            data:model,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadModal").html(data);
                $('#modal-manage-department').modal('show')
            }
        })
    }
```

**I would like to do something like this:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick='toggleManageDepartmentModal(Eval("department" + @department.Id))'>
                                <span class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                Rediger
                            </button>
```

Comment: If I understand well this is a server side rendering code (this first snippet), so can you just remove the eval et let what's inside it ? The js will be executed normally on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a little different approch which works very well.

```
@foreach (var department in Model.PaginatedDepartments())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@department.Name</td>
                    <td>@department.Description</td>
                    <td class="min">@department.Created.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td>
                    <td class="min">
                        <div class="text-nowrap">
                            <script>
                                //Store model JSON in localStorage
                                localStorage.setItem('department' + @department.Id, JSON.stringify(@Json.Serialize(department)))
                            </script>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="toggleManageDepartmentModal(@department.Id)">
                                <span class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                Rediger
                            </button>
                        </div>   
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }


function toggleManageDepartmentModal(id) {
        var modelJSON = localStorage.getItem('department' + id);

        var model = {
            department : JSON.parse(modelJSON),
            controller : 'Admin',
            action : 'ManageDepartment'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Modals/ShowManageDepartmentModal",
            data:model,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadModal").html(data);
                $('#modal-manage-department').modal('show')
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly familiar with the tool (a templating engine?) you are using to build your HTML, but I will try to help.

Traditionally, before the JS framework takeover, the way to attach data to HTML elements was to use `data-attributes`. In your case, I would use something like `data-department`. I would dare to say that it's much better way then using `script` tags + `eval()`

The simplest way would be to attach the data to the button. Probably like a serialized JSON:

```html
<button data-department="@DataGoesHere" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
Rediger</button>
```

How about the `onclick` function? You can get the button's reference by using `this` argument:

```html
<button onclick="toggleManageDepartmentModal(this)" data-department="@DataGoesHere" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
Rediger</button>
```

Then, you can access the data by querying `this.dataset.department`:

```js
function toggleManageDepartmentModal(targetElement) {
    // `this` is event's target element
    const department = targetElement.dataset.department;
    // or rather JSON.parse(targetElement.dataset.department)
    // or targetElm.getAttribute('data-department')
    …
}
```

There's one caveat – because `data-attribute`s are part of the 'public' markup, you really should not put anything confidential in there (but I guess that this is not the case).

Comment: Passing @department into data-department will only give me the full namespace name of the object, not the object itself.

Like:
ActivityPlanner.Domain.Models.Department

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the backend you are using. You need to do something like `data-department=@Json.Serialize(department)`, but I can't tell you how exactly. But it is strange that you are getting the interface, not the data. Isn't there a method like `@department.getAttributes()`?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio with MVC .net core 6. 

I already tried that. That will only give me the first {, the rest is stripped. I think that is because data- attribute is only for simple, literal types, not objects or JSON

Comment: The attribute value should be string, yes, but it includes stringified JSON (though there is probably a length restriction). You can, however, use multiple separate data-attributes, like `data-id="42"`, `data-username="John Doe"` etc. I can't help you with the specific syntax, though – I've never written any .net code. Maybe try to wrap the data in  `.toString()` call?

Comment: I would like to do something like this:
onclick='toggleManageDepartmentModal(Eval("department" + @department.Id))'>